# React + rails Application AAD and OpenID connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm deeveloping an application that uses React (nextjs to be more accurate) and Ruby on rails as my back end. Althought, i'm trying to use AAD as my Identiity provider.

I need to know if my approuch using OIDC it's correct and how to implement it as well.

Following the protocol rules (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc), the first thing i'm trying, and failing, is to get user sign-in to get the authorization_code and then exchange that to an access_token in my backend.

```js
    window.location.assign(
      url.build({
        host: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AAD_AUTHORITY,
        path: "/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
        query: {
          response_type: "code id_token",
          client_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AAD_CLIENT_ID,
          scope: "openid https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
          redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/callback",
          response_mode: "form_post",
          nonce: code_challenge,
          code_challenge_method: "S256",
          code_challenge: code_challenge,
        },
      })
    );
```

Since i'm using OICD, the response mode must be "form_post" or "fragment".

[form_data_request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdHnj.png)

My problem is that i have no idea how to receive this kind of response, since i'm not using fetch (generates CORS errors) that its it thenable.

So....any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach using [OIDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols) is correct because rails fully support OIDC. To implement you need to configure the tenant in Azure AD then register a new app in you tenant Azure Active Directory. Go to Azure portal and click on “App registration” and on “New registration”. Lastly, move to your rails app and then integrate your application with Azure active directory. [Here](https://medium.com/committed-engineers/setup-azure-ad-oauth-2-0-with-ruby-on-rails-and-devise-39848e3ed532) is a complete guide that can direct you.